# one to multiple many relationship

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Consider two tables as mentioned below -

**Table1** (id_col, name_col)
**Table2** (uid_col, code_col_1, code_col_2)

where, 
**id_col** is primary key for Table1
**uid_col** is primary key for Table2
and, **id_col** has one to many relationship with both **code_col_1** and **code_col_2**

Records could look like:- 
Table1
1, xxx
2, yyy

Table2
11, 1, 2 
12, 2, 1 
12, 2, 2 

How will the JPA look like in following classes?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Table1")
public class T1 {
    @OneToMany(targetEntity=T2.class, mappedBy="??????", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<T2> t2; //???not sure about this
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Table2")
public class T2 {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="code_col_1")
    private T1 t1;  //???not sure what goes here
}
```

Comment: what are the primary keys for table 1 ? And what are the primary keys for table 2 ?  Also what do mean by "record in a column" ?

Comment: edited the question...hope its clearer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a one-to-many association; rather, it's two separate many-to-one associations from   `T2` to `T1`. You'd map both on `T2` side:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Table2")
public class T2 {
  @Id // map whatever generator you'd like
  private long id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="code_col_1")
  private T1 t1_code1;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="code_col_2")
  private T1 t1_code2;
}
```

Mapping the reverse one-to-many associations from `T1` to `T2` is not a good idea because you risk having (some of) the same elements in both collections which will result in all sorts of troubles during inserts / deletes.

Comment: Thanks for the help! But I still am confused, with the many to one association coming into play is it possible for Table2 to hold null values for code_col_1 or code_col_2 something like (13, null, null)?

Comment: @Mohammad - yes, by default @ManyToOne association can be null on owner's end. If you'd rather disallow nulls, you can do so via `optional` attribute: `@ManyToOne(optional=false)